# How to search for an array of patterns in another array using Google Script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, pattern-matching

Using two arrays, I want to find patternArray[] items in myArray[].
If there is a match, I want to add the match from myArray to foundArray.

My current code gives me the following error;

> TypeError: Cannot call method "search" of undefined. (line

could any one tell me how to fix the above error ?Furthermore, Does this solution find multiple matches in myArray ?
(for example if "red apple"(from patternArray) found more then once in myArray i want to add both to foundArray.)

```
function  findpattern()
{

  var foundArray=[];
  var NotfoundArray=[];

  var foundStringCounter=0;
  var NotfoundStringCounter=0;

 var myArray=["red apple http://awebsite.com/1.jpg","green apple http://1awebsite.com/2.jpg","red apple http://1awebsite.com/3.jpg"];

 var patternArray= ["green apple","red apple","mango","orange tree","cherry tree","banana store","grape tree"];


  var patternArraySize = patternArray.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < patternArraySize; i++)
    {
    var result = myArray[i].search(patternArray[i]);
    //var result = myArray[i].indexOf(patternArray[i]);

  if (result == -1) {

    NotfoundArray.push(myArray[i]);
    NotfoundStringCounter++;

  } else {

    foundArray.push(myArray[i]);
    foundStringCounter++;

  }
  result="";  
    }



  Logger.log(foundStringCounter);
  Logger.log(foundArray);

   Logger.log(NotfoundStringCounter);
  Logger.log(NotfoundArray); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works:

```
function  findpattern() {

  var foundArray=[],
      NotfoundArray=[],
      foundStringCounter=0,
      NotfoundStringCounter=0;

  var myArray=["red apple http://awebsite.com/1.jpg",
               "green apple http://1awebsite.com/2.jpg",
               "red apple http://1awebsite.com/3.jpg",
               "rotten apple http://rottenApple.com"];

  var patternArray= ["green apple","red apple","mango","orange tree","cherry tree","banana store","grape tree"];
  var patternArraySize = patternArray.length;

  Logger.log('patternArraySize: ' + patternArraySize);

  var i=0,
      j=0,
      thisUrl="",
      thisPattern="",
      isMatched=0,
      outerArray = [];

  for (i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

    thisUrl = myArray[i];
    foundStringCounter = 0; //Reset
    temporaryArray = []; //Reset

    for (j=0; j<patternArraySize; j+=1) {
      thisPattern = patternArray[j];
      isMatched = thisUrl.indexOf(thisPattern);

      if (isMatched !== -1) {
        foundArray.push(thisUrl);
        foundStringCounter++;
      };

    };

    if (foundStringCounter===0) {
      NotfoundArray.push(thisUrl);
    };

    outerArray.push(foundArray);
  };

  Logger.log('foundArray: ' + foundArray);
  Logger.log('NotfoundArray: ' + NotfoundArray);
  Logger.log('outerArray: ' + outerArray);
};

var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
currentSheet
  .getRange(currentSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1,outerArray.length,foundArray.length)
  .setValues(outerArray);
```

Comment: Many thanks . what is difference between using myArray as outer FOR loop instead of patternArray?

Comment: It could probably be done either way, but using `myArray` in the outer loop  is the way that is more understandable to me.  The `myArray` holds the elements to be found and returned.  You aren't trying to extract anything from `patternArray`.  Plus, this way, if there are two matches, they are found from just "one and the same" iteration of the outer loop.  If you did it the other way around, the multiple matches would come from different iterations of the outer loop.  Which just seems a little confusing to me.

Comment: Good explanation .So For finding pattern we should use indexof instead of search and search is for exact match?

Comment: I just tested `indexOf()` against `search()` in Apps Script, and `indexOf()` was faster.  They both return a position value, but `search()` can match multiple findings with regEx.  So, maybe `search()` is doing more processing.  For this code, multiple matches and regEx isn't necessary.

Comment: So the output(foundArray[] size and data in this case) using either indexof or search will be the same only the speed will be different? How i can add(append to its end)  foundArray content to spreadsheet columnA ?

Comment: Get a reference to the spreadsheet, then the sheet, then use the `appendRow()` method.  [Google Documentation - appendRow() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))

Comment: i tried to use  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(12, 1, foundArray.length, 1).setValues(foundArray); but script editor complains that it is not multidimensional array!(Cannot convert Array to Object[][]. (line...)How to convert it to multidimensional array ?

Comment: `var outerArray = [];  outerArray.push(foundArray); SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(12, 1, 1, foundArray.length).setValues(outerArray);`

Comment: Many thanks but it writes all array items in one row . I want each item in separate row of column A.

Comment: I updated the answer.  The code needed to be changed a little bit.